# complex number passing from $|z|^{2}$ to $|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I really couldn't understand last part when they pass from $|z|^{2}$ to $|z|$
so any more explanation please?

> [image: complex numbers]

Comment: Perhaps $$z\overline z=|z|^2\Longleftrightarrow \frac{|z|^2}{z}=\overline z\,\,,\,\,z\neq 0\,\,\,?$$

Comment: I'm looking for $|z|$ not $\overline z$ nor $z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply expand:
$$\left(-a + \sqrt{a^2+4}\right)^2 = 2\left(a^2 + 2 - \sqrt{a^4+4a^2}\right)$$
If $|z|^2 > r^2$ it follows that $|z|>r$...

Comment: I didn't get the point of expanding this expression.

Comment: @pourjour - the two expression are exactly the ones you need, are they not?

Comment: ok I get it thanks

Comment: Maybe clearer to write: $$\left(\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2+4}}2\right)^2 = \left(\frac{a^2 + 2 - \sqrt{a^4+4a^2}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: how about doing this by respecting the steps and not reversly?

Comment: @pourjour - why do things the hard way? I don't see an obvious way of getting this by "respecting the steps".